# Linq to xml parsing

Tags: c#, linq

I need assistance in retrieving the element Country and Its value 1 in the below code. 
Thanks in advance.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<env:Contentname xmlns:env="http://data.schemas" xmlns="http://2013-02-01/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <env:Body>
       <env:Content action="Hello">
         <env:Data xsi:type="Yellow">
         </env:Data>
       </env:Content>

      <env:Content action="Hello">
         <env:Data xsi:type="Red">
           <Status xmlns="http://2010-10-10/">
             <Id >39681</Id>
             <Name>Published</Name>
           </Status>
        </env:Data>
      </env:Content>

      <env:Content action="Hello">
        <env:Data xsi:type="green">
          <Document>
            <Country>1</Country>   
          </Document>
        </env:Data>
      </env:Content>
  </env:Body>
</env:Contentname>
```

I tried this,

```
          var result = from x in root.Descendants(aw + "Data")

          where (string)x.Attribute(kw + "type") == "green"

          select x;


        foreach (var item in result)
        {
            var str = item.Element("Document").Element("Country");
            Console.WriteLine(str.Value);
        }
```

But i am getting error.(Object reference not set to an instance of an object.)
kindly help me with this.

Comment: Yes it was not valid and now u check pa

Answer (score 1):

This is the problem, for two reasons:

```
var str = item.Element("Document").Element("country");
```

Firstly, XML is case-sensitive - you want `Country`, not `country`.

Secondly, those elements inherit the namespace declared with `xmlns=...` in the root element. You need:

```
XNamespace ns = "http://2013-02-01/";
...
var element = item.Element(ns + "Document").Element(ns + "Country");
```

I'd also encourage you to avoid query expressions where they don't actually buy you much. In this case, you could perform the whole query in one go using the `Elements` extension method which works on sequences of input elements, assuming you don't mind finding *every* `Document -> Country` element rather than just one per `Data`:

```
var query = root.Descendants(aw + "Data")
                .Where(x => (string)x.Attribute(kw + "type") == "green")
                .Elements(ns + "Document")
                .Elements(ns + "Country")
                .Select(x => x.Value);
foreach (var item in query)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

One significant difference - this *won't* fall over with an exception if there is a `Data` element with `xsi:type='green'` which doesn't have a `Document -> Country` element. If you want it to (to find bad data) you could use:

```
var query = root.Descendants(aw + "Data")
                .Where(x => (string)x.Attribute(kw + "type") == "green")
                .Select(x => x.Element(ns + "Document")
                              .Element(ns + "Country")
                              .Value);
```

To show a short but complete example, this code (with your XML as `test.xml`) gives an output of "1":

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;

public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var doc = XDocument.Load("test.xml");
        XNamespace ns = "http://2013-02-01/";
        XNamespace kw = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";
        XNamespace aw = "http://data.schemas";
        var query = doc.Descendants(aw + "Data")
                .Where(x => (string)x.Attribute(kw + "type") == "green")
                .Elements(ns + "Document")
                .Elements(ns + "Country")
                .Select(x => x.Value);
        foreach (var item in query)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: M not getting any answer

Comment: @VenkateshVenky: That doesn't give us *any* information. For a start, I've given you three different pieces of code, and we don't know which you've tried. Next, "not getting any anser" doesn't tell us what you're seeing. Are you still getting an exception? No exception, but no output? What?

Comment: @VenkateshVenky: I've now included a short but *complete* program demonstrating the middle example working.

Comment: Now m not getting any exception.

Comment: @VenkateshVenky: Well I've shown in my answer that my code gives the right results with the XML you've shown us, so you should compare that with your code which isn't working. I can't tell what's wrong without seeing the code you're using. As an aside, I now see you've used "m" instead of "I'm" several times - to make communication easier, I'd strongly advise you to use full English words.

Comment: Super I got the answer and Thanks a lot @Jon Skeet

Comment: I have one more question how can i change the attribute value "Hello".

Comment: @VenkateshVenky: If you have another question, you should ask it in another post - with suitable details, sample XML, and a short but complete program showing what you've tried so far and explaining what happens compared with what you want to happen.